# Inserting data into database using if statement

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I wrote a code to insert input data to database using codeigniter but before inserting, data will go through an if statement to check the input then if condition is met data will be saved.

I was trying to check if the input data is equal to section then parent id must be 0. Else if not section then the $data['type'] entered must be inserted to database and parent id must not be 0.
This is my code so far.

```
$data = array (
'title' => $this->input->post->('title'),
'type' => $this->input->post->('type'),
'description' => $this->input->post->('description')
); 


if ($data['type'] == 'section') {
         $data['parent_id'] = 0;
       } else {
         $data['parent_id']  = $this->input->post('parent_id');
         $data['type']  = $this->input->post('type');
       }
 $result = $this->checklist_item_model->put_item($data);
```

Model

```
public function put_item ($data) {
   $this->db->insert('items', $data);
 }
```

Comment: Where is your insert query or model code!!

Comment: I edited the code above pls have a look

Answer (score 1):

You can create you condition as

```
if($this->input->post('type')=='section')
{
$data = array(
 'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
 'type' => $this->input->post('type'),
 'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
 'parent_id' => 0// if section==0 condition
);
} else {
    $data = array(
    'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
    'type' => $this->input->post('type'),
    'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
    'parent_id' => $this->input->post('parent_id')
    );
}

 $result = $this->checklist_item_model->put_item($data);
```

Comment: got an error syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Comment: AHHH!! my bad remove `->` after post! Check updated answer!!

Comment: the code run but I got the same error. it only insert the section input

Comment: If you got same error then this code will never run!! I think you miss something!! Check your column name and array key

Comment: Else statement runs and I check the data inserted using var_dump on the type then it displays my input but not inserted to the database.

Comment: I get it now. It's because of my database field type which is enum which is case sensitive.

Comment: glad to know you got your mistake!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary operator to simplify your code

```
$data = array (
    'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
    'type' => $this->input->post('type'),
    'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
    'parent_id' => ($this->input->post('parent_id') == 'section') ? 0 : $this->input->post('parent_id');
); 
$result = $this->checklist_item_model->put_item($data);
```

And, in the model you can return the last insert id like this

```
public function put_item ($data) {
    $this->db->insert('items', $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: This one is helpful too. Using only short type of if else condition.

Comment: Your solution is good and efficient just remove `->` after post to make it syntax error free